# Trouble defining interface correctly TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y' and with using a vue ref

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am having trouble with some defining issues with typescript in Vue. I am getting `TS2339: Property 'product' does not exist on type '(LineItem[] | undefined)[K]'.` I am not sure if it doesn't like `'orderedItems': Array<LineItem>` or if the way I am setting the ref value and using it in the component.

I notice that when I console log `purchaseInfo.value?.orderedItems` that deep object is still in a proxy and not unwrapped properly.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

interface LineItem {
  'product': {
    'id': number,
    'sku': string,
    'title': string,
    'price': string,
    'image': string,
    'description': string,
  },
  'quantity': number;
}

export interface PurchaseInfo {
  'address': string,
  'city': string,
  'zipCode': string,
  'orderedItems': Array<LineItem>,
  'orderStatus': string
}

let purchaseInfo = ref<PurchaseInfo | undefined>();

onMounted(async () => {
  // this function fetchPurchaseInfo() returns a Promise<PurchaseInfo> which is return response.data as PurchaseInfo;
  purchaseInfo.value = await fetchPurchaseInfo() 
})

</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="purchaseInfo">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in purchaseInfo?.orderedItems">
      <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
      <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.product.title }}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `ref` without initial value it is `undefined` by default. This also affects the type, so `purchaseInfo` is actually `Ref<PurchaseInfo | undefined>`.

So you just need a check in the template to handle the loading state, when `purchaseInfo` has no value yet:

```html
<template>
  <table v-if="purchaseInfo">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in purchaseInfo.orderedItems" />
  </table>
  <div v-else>
    You can put some loader here, or render nothing.
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I should of mentioned I actually do check if `purchaseInfo` is there with a `<div v-if="purchaseInfo">` container around everything. I still have the error.  I updated my example to show the container.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I can say what fixed this. It looks like the compiler kept picking up on something bad and decided to start building fine.